# Convert non-generic method to generic method

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, marshalling

I have following method:

```
private <U> void fun(U u) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(u.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(u, System.out);
    }
```

marshal() method takes different types of arguments. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)
It takes:

1. ContentHandler
2. OutputStream
3. XmlEventWriter
4. XMLStreamWriter etc.

How to modify the above method such that instead of `System.out` , I can pass the destination of marshalling in function argument.

For e.g. I want to call method like:

```
objToXml(obj1,System.out);
outToXml(obj1,file_pointer);
```

Likewise.

I tried following with `fun(obj1,PrintStream.class,System.out)` but it was unsuccessfull:

```
private <T, U, V> void fun(T t, Class<U> u, V v) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(t.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(t, (U) v);
    }
```

Comment: The type `U` in your first code is completely unnecessary; you can just use `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add additional generic parameters to your method. Simply pass a javax.xml.transform.Result to the marshaller:

```
private <U> void fun(U u, Result result) {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(u.getClass());
  Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
  marshaller.marshal(u, result);
}
```

You can use the StreamResult for writing to System.out or to a file:

```
fun(foo, new StreamResult(System.out));
fun(foo, new StreamResult(file_pointer.openOutputStream()));
```

Comment: It works for console and file but what about others? please see the update.

Comment: Well, what do you need? What you can do with a Result is rather extensive: you can write to Streams/Writers and to various XML APIs (DOM, SAX, StAX). If that is not sufficient, you can always overload your `fun` method to use other Marshaller.marshal implementations.